# Combining data between three tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a site *(For School Purpose)* where you can buy stuff from different companies.
On one of the sites I want to show all the companies, but only the companies from the category and the city you have chosen.

But I also want it to be ordered by popularity.
For every time a person is buying something, the popularity of the company in the chosen category and city will be raised by 1.

The categories are: Men, Women and Family.

For this, I'm using three tables:

**Table 1 - partners**

```
|  partner_id  |  name  |  type  |  logo  |
```

In the first table I have the company names, type and logo.
This table is only used to get the name, type and logo from each company.

---

**Table 2 - single_partners**

```
|  id  |  partner_id  |  address  |  zipcode  |  city  |
```

In the second table I have all companies in the entire country.
If one compay is located multiple times in one city, there will be multiple rows, but with a different id, address, zipcode and city. The partner_id will be the same of course.

---

**Table 3 - partner_pupolarity**

```
|  id  |  partner_id  |  men  |  women  |  family  |
```

In the third table the popularity of each company will be.
Here each company from every city will be stored with a popularity value *(men, women and family)*. If the company have no popularity in any of the three categories, it won't be stored in the table.

I can show each companies from each city, but I cannot sort it by popularity according to the category.

---

**Heres is an quick example of what I want:**

On the first site you can choose a category: *Men, Women or Family*.
When you have chosen a category, you are going to choose a city by typing the zip-code.

Then you're going to see a list where the most popular companies will be shown, sorted by the category you have chosen, and the city. If a company exist multiple times in the same city, it should only show one.

If you have chosen Men and City 1, you will se the most popular companies from the men category in City 1.

If a company do not have any popularity value from that category, it will be in the bottom of the companies.

---

What I can do now is only to show the companies according to the city you have chosen, but I can's sort them by popularity.

This is what I have tried:

```
// Load partners
$load_partners = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partners");
while($partners = mysql_fetch_array($load_partners)) {

    $partner_id = $partners['partner_id'];
    $partner_name = $partners['name'];
    $partner_logo = $partners['logo'];
    $partner_logo_dir = "media/partners/";

    $load_single_partners = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT '$partner_name' FROM single_partners WHERE partner_id='$partner_id' and postal='5000'");
    while($single_partners = mysql_fetch_array($load_single_partners)) {

        $single_partners_id = $single_partners['partner_id'];


            echo '<div class="partner" style="background: url('.$partner_logo_dir.$partner_logo.'); background-size: cover;" data-partner-id="'.$partner_id.'">'.$partner_name.'
        </div>'."\n";
        $order_partners = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partner_popularity WHERE partner_id = '$single_partners_id'");
        while($order = mysql_fetch_array($order_partners)) {
        }
    }
}
```

I think I somehow should combine the data from the three tables but I do not know how.

..or am I doing it all wrong by using three different tables?

Hope you can understand by question :)

Comment: There are some things i dont understand, at one point you said that companies wont be stored in the table if they had no rep, but after you say that you want them at the bottom of the list, wouldnt it just be easier to store them all even if rep is 0? i'd start designing a 'JOIN' select to join all three tables.

Comment: And what is the point of having partners and single_partners? even if there are two diferent companies in the same city you want them to appear as one!

Comment: Because when you click at the company, a box will pop up, where you can choose between the multiple companies from that city.

And also so I only have one place to define the type, name and logo of the company

Comment: Ok, so the same company can have different rep in diferent cities?

Comment: yes. If we for example have Four of the same companies in the same city, they will all have the same rep in each category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to achieve this is using joins : [Here is some MySQL doc about this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

But here, using 2 tables for single partners and popularity is not really needed, since one line of single_partners is strictly equal to one line of partner_popularty, you can put them in the same table. You should put them in the same table, and using a default of zero if the partner has no popularity registered, so it'll show last when sorting by popularity.

So, then you'll have 2 tables :

Table 1 - partners

```
|  partner_id  |  name  |  type  |  logo  |
```

Table 2 - single_partners

```
|  id  |  partner_id  |  address  |  zipcode  |  city  | pop_men | pop_women | pop_family
```

Now your query to select all that becomes extremely simple (just select the partners, filter the city, order them and you're done), and with a little grouping and a join, you can also select partners sorted by popularity summarized in all cities :

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUM(pop_men) AS total_pop_men,
       SUM(pop_women) AS total_pop_women,
       SUM(pop_family) AS total_pop_family
FROM partners p
JOIN single_partners sp ON sp.partner_id = p.partner_id
GROUP BY partner_id
ORDER BY total_pop_men DESC,
         total_pop_women DESC,
         total_pop_family DESC
```

Comment: So the code above should be inserted inside the code where I filter the city?

Comment: No, it was just an example of the extent of this table rearrangement. The code you posted can already do the trick, you just need to put the "ORDER BY" clauses (like the one I used, but with pop_* fields instead) at the end of your SELECT DISTINCT query. Don't forget to also select the pop_* fields also, or you won't get much things.

Comment: I have tried to change ´SELECT * FROM partners´ to ´SELECT * SUM(pop_men) AS total_pop_men FROM partners p´ and put in ´ORDER BY total_pop_men DESC´ in the end of the SELECT DISTINCT query but nothing is happening.

Anything I've done wrong?
http://pastie.org/private/gnbf0vyfwcokfy2g3hnjaa

Comment: You've mixed everything. First, you try to use generated fields between two queries. That doesn't work. Then, your way of getting the partners is not gonna work like this, because you're trying to get them by name, then by popularity. So a partner got in the main loop before the other will be shown before, even if its popularity is lower. Think about what you need to get in first place : single_partners, ordered. So the main query (and loop) will be on single_partners. Check this approach : http://koinko.in/ini11 and here is it running with some data : http://koinko.in/ICm9d

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT partners.name FROM partners, single_partners, partner_popularity
WHERE single_partners.name = 'cityname' AND partners.id = single_partners.partner_id AND
partners.id = partner_populariry.partner_id ORDER BY partner_popularity.[category]
```

As far as i can understand this is what your looking for, or something similar, i dont really understand the whole meaning of it, it this select you will have to do three diferent ones, one for each category.

Sorry if i didn't help.